# K6: How to apply custom resource in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, k6, kubernetes-go-client

Currently we could create configmaps, deployment, pods, jobs, namespaces, ingress.

https://github.com/grafana/xk6-kubernetes

But I would like to deploy custom resources. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes (assuming the CustomResourceDefinition already exists in the cluster).  What is the specific programming-related problem you're running into?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> But I would like to deploy custom resources. Is it possible?

Creation of CR is possible.  If definitions are maintained in yaml files for Custom resources, then CR can be applied or created using kubectl tool.

Usually Custom resources are associated with CRD's or API aggregators.  Please refer kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) for more details.

[Adding custom resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#adding-custom-resources)

Kubernetes provides two ways to add custom resources to your cluster:

CRDs are simple and can be created without any programming.
API Aggregation requires programming, but allows more control over API behaviors like how data is stored and conversion between API versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not presently possible. Even when the recently introduced [generic interface](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-kubernetes/releases/tag/v0.2.0) there are some issues regarding how Kubernetes API handles CRDs. Please refer to [this open issue](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-kubernetes/issues/69) for tracking the progress of this requirement.